# Select data divided in groups evenly distributed by value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I would like to select into 4 groups the data from a table having the sum of a values in the groups as evenly distributed possible. I am sure that I am not explaining it clear enough so I will try to give an example.

Here I use NTILE(4) to create the 4 groups:

```
SELECT Time, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY Time DESC) AS N FROM TableX

Time -  N
-------------
10  -   1
 9  -   2
 8  -   3
 7  -   4
 6  -   1
 5  -   2
 4  -   3
 3  -   4
 2  -   1
 1  -   2
```

In the above query and result, the other columns have been omitted for brevity.

So you can see the groups also as follows:

```
  1    2    3    4
---  ---  ---  ---
 10    9    8    7
  6    5    4    3
  2    1    
---  ---  ---  ---
 18   15   12   10  Sum Totals of Time
```

Notice that the Sum Totals of Time using NTile is not really balanced between the groups. A better distribution of the Time values would be for example:

```
  1    2    3    4
---  ---  ---  ---
 10    9    8    7
  3    5    4    6
  1         2
---  ---  ---  ---
 14   14   14   13  Sum Totals of Time
```

Here the Sum Totals of Time is more evenly distributed over the 4 groups.

How can I perform this through a TSQL statements?

Furthermore I have to say that I am using SQL Server 2012.
If you have something that can help me out, let me know.

I wish you a nice day.

Stan

Comment: Are your values always integers? If so, are they in a continuous series or can there be gaps? Unique values?

Comment: Hi, yes they are integers, and no they are not continuous, some maybe double and sure gaps are between them. Imagine them that it is the time needed to perform an operation for that particular item (the particular item is an omitted column).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a stab at an algorithm. It's not perfect, and depending on how much time you want to spend refining it, there are probably some further small gains to be made.

Let's assume you have a table of tasks to be performed by four queues. You know the amount of work associated with performing each task, and you want all four queues to get an almost equal amount of work to do, so all queues will complete at about the same time.

First off, I'd partition the tasks using a modulous, ordered by their size, from small to large.

```
SELECT [time], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [time])%4 AS grp, 0
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` orders every row by size, then assigns a row number, starting at 1. This row number is assigned a "group" (the `grp` column) on a round-robin basis. First row is group 1, second row is group 2, then 3, the fourth gets group 0, and so on.

```
time ROW_NUMBER() grp
---- ------------ ---
   1            1   1
  10            2   2
  12            3   3
  15            4   0
  19            5   1
  22            6   2
...
```

For ease of use, I'm storing the `time` and `grp` columns in a table variable called `@work`.

Now, we can perform a few calculations on this data:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
             -SUM([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL))/4 AS _grpoffset
    FROM @work)
...
```

The column `_grpoffset` is how much the total `time` per `grp` differs from the "ideal" average. If the total `time` of the all tasks is 1000 and there are four groups, there should ideally be a total of 250 in each group. If a group contains a total of 268, that group's `_grpoffset=18`.

The idea is to identify the two best rows, one in a "positive" group (with too much work) and one in a "negative" group (with too little work). If we can swap groups on those two rows, we could reduce the absolute `_grpoffset` of both groups.

Example:

```
time grp total _grpoffset
---- --- ----- ----------
   3   1   222         40
  46   1   222         40
  73   1   222         40
 100   1   222         40
   6   2   134        -48
  52   2   134        -48
  76   2   134        -48
  11   3   163        -21
  66   3   163        -21
  86   3   163        -21
  45   0   208         24
  71   0   208         24
  92   0   208         24
----
=727
```

With a grand total of 727, each group should have a score of about 182 for the distribution to be perfect. The difference between the group's score and 182 is what we're putting in the `_grpoffset` column.

As you can see now, in the best of worlds, we should move about 40 points worth of rows from group 1 to group 2 and about 24 points from group 3 to group 0.

Here's the code to identify those candidate rows:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 pos._row AS _pos_row, pos.grp AS _pos_grp,
                 neg._row AS _neg_row, neg.grp AS _neg_grp
    FROM cte AS pos
    INNER JOIN cte AS neg ON
        pos._grpoffset>0 AND
        neg._grpoffset<0 AND
        --- To prevent infinite recursion:
        pos.moved<4 AND
        neg.moved<4
    WHERE --- must improve positive side's offset:
          ABS(pos._grpoffset-pos.[time]+neg.[time])<=pos._grpoffset AND
          --- must improve negative side's offset:
          ABS(neg._grpoffset-neg.[time]+pos.[time])<=ABS(neg._grpoffset)
    --- Largest changes first:
    ORDER BY ABS(pos.[time]-neg.[time]) DESC
    ) AS x ON w._row IN (x._pos_row, x._neg_row);
```

I'm self-joining the common table expression that we created before, `cte`: On one side, groups with a positive `_grpoffset`, on the other side groups with negative ones. To further filter out which rows are supposed to match each other, the swap of the positive and negative sides' rows must improve `_grpoffset`, i.e. get it closer to 0.

The `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` selects the "best" match to swap first.

Now, all we need to to is add an `UPDATE`, and loop it until there's no more optimization to be found.

**TL;DR - here's the query**

Here's the complete code:

```
DECLARE @work TABLE (
    _row    int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [time]  int NOT NULL,
    grp     int NOT NULL,
    moved   tinyint NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([time], _row)
);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 0 AS n, CAST(1+100*RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) AS int) AS [time]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1,    CAST(1+100*RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) AS int) AS [time]
    FROM cte WHERE n<100)

INSERT INTO @work ([time], grp, moved)
SELECT [time], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [time])%4 AS grp, 0
FROM cte;



WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT!=0)
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT *, SUM([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY grp)
                 -SUM([time]) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL))/4 AS _grpoffset
        FROM @work)

    UPDATE w
    SET w.grp=(CASE w._row
               WHEN x._pos_row THEN x._neg_grp
               ELSE x._pos_grp END),
        w.moved=w.moved+1
    FROM @work AS w
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TOP 1 pos._row AS _pos_row, pos.grp AS _pos_grp,
                     neg._row AS _neg_row, neg.grp AS _neg_grp
        FROM cte AS pos
        INNER JOIN cte AS neg ON
            pos._grpoffset>0 AND
            neg._grpoffset<0 AND
            --- To prevent infinite recursion:
            pos.moved<4 AND
            neg.moved<4
        WHERE --- must improve positive side's offset:
              ABS(pos._grpoffset-pos.[time]+neg.[time])<=pos._grpoffset AND
              --- must improve negative side's offset:
              ABS(neg._grpoffset-neg.[time]+pos.[time])<=ABS(neg._grpoffset)
        --- Largest changes first:
        ORDER BY ABS(pos.[time]-neg.[time]) DESC
        ) AS x ON w._row IN (x._pos_row, x._neg_row);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works well and runs quickly on large datasets.

I was dealing with data kind of like this:

```
pk_value     employee_id SomeValue
------------ ----------- ----------
97875250314  1           SomeValue1
98001185450  1           SomeValue2
97926729191  1           SomeValue3
98028101823  2           SomeValue1
97997295004  2           SomeValue2
97875250314  3           SomeValue1
98001185451  3           SomeValue2
97926729192  4           SomeValue1
98028101824  5           SomeValue1
...
```

What we needed to accomplish was to evenly distribute records across a certain number of buckets while isolating employee_ids to ONLY one bucket regardless how many records that one employee had. For the data above, we needed it to break down like this, for lets say 3 buckets.

```
bucket_id  emp_count   no_of_records
---------- ----------- -------------
1          1 (eid 1)   3
2          2 (eid 2,4) 3
3          2 (eid 3,5) 3
...
```

For the 9 records in the sample set, employee 1 had 3, employees 2 and 3 had 2 each, and employees 4 and 5 had 1 each. Distributing them above in that way allowed for each employee to belong to only 1 bucket, while still creating buckets of equal size.

In order to record this, we would have to add a column to the original dataset containing what bucket the records belongs to.

```
pk_value     employee_id SomeValue  bucket_id
------------ ----------- ---------- ----------
97875250314  1           SomeValue1 1
98001185450  1           SomeValue2 1
97926729191  1           SomeValue3 1
98028101823  2           SomeValue1 2
...
```

If the dataset were laid out like that, we could create the aggregated dataset by running the code below.

```
SELECT bucket_id
     , COUNT(employee_id) AS emp_count
     , SUM(SomeValue) AS no_of_records
FROM sourcetable
GROUP BY bucket_id
ORDER BY bucket_id
```

So lets say we have a table with that schema above. We could do all the aggregations on the source data table, but if you are working with production data or a very large dataset, I found it easier to work with an aggregated representation of the table, since the values of the records themselves don't really matter - it's the count per employee that we are interested in.

So we create an aggregated mapping table to do our work on -

```
CREATE TABLE #bucket_mapping
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , emp_id INT NOT NULL
  , records_for_emp INT NOT NULL
  , bucket_id INT NOT NULL
        DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON #bucket_mapping (bucket_id, records_for_emp);
```

This table contains the employee id and a count of how many records they have, all first assigned to bucket_id 0. Since I was dealing with very large datasets I put a primary key on the identity column and added a nonclustered index on bucket_id and records_for_emp, but for smaller datasets neither of those are really necessary and could possibly slow down performance.

Insert the aggregated source data into the mapping table -

```
INSERT INTO #bucket_mapping
(
    emp_id
  , records_for_emp
)
SELECT employee_id
     , COUNT(1) as records_for_emp
FROM sourcetable
GROUP BY employee_id
ORDER BY records_for_emp DESC;
```

Now, the overarching concept for this solution is a **three-pass** sorting algorithm.

The **first pass** loops across each bucket, distributing the number of records per employee, sorted largest to smallest, using Run Length Encoding to greatly minimize the number of looping iterations.

Since the first pass leaves the last bucket larger than the others, the **second pass** distributes back across each bucket, ordered from record count fewest to greatest, the smallest employee in the final bucket with a records count > 1 until the final bucket is under the intended size.

The **final pass** takes any remaining single-records employees, **n**, and distributes them across the top **n** buckets, ordered fewest records to most in one execution.

Declare some variables - these will all be explained when they are used.

```
DECLARE @currentBucket INT = 1
      , @totalBucketCount INT = 50
      , @currentID INT = 0
      , @lastID INT
      , @numberOfRecords INT
      , @bucketID INT
      , @currentBucketSize INT = 0
      , @maxBucketSize INT
      , @batchThreshold INT
      , @lengthOfRun INT
      , @batchEndID INT
      , @totalRecords INT;
```

To determine the total number of **records** being processed and the desired size of each bucket, the variables are set below -

```
SELECT @totalRecords = SUM(records_for_emp)
     , @maxBucketSize = SUM(records_for_emp) / @totalBucketCount
FROM #bucket_mapping;
```

The first thing to do is separate these out logically into **2 groups** - employees with a record count no other employee has, and employees that share record counts with other employees. Think back to the example dataset above. Employee 1 was the only employee with 3 records, while 2 and 3 shared a count of 2 records and 4 and 5 shared a count of 1.

When looked at through the lens of Run Length Encoding (RLE), the employees that have a unique record count are treated as single data items, and the employees that share record counts with other employees are treated as runs of data items.

To determine the record count and run length of the first run of data items, the variables are stored with the values below -

```
SELECT TOP 1
       @batchThreshold = records_for_emp
     , @lengthOfRun = COUNT(1) as length_of_run
FROM #bucket_mapping
WHERE bucket_id = 0
GROUP BY records_for_emp
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY records_for_emp DESC;
```

For my dataset, the top 3 runs were these.

```
records_for_emp length_of_run
--------------- -------------
12252           2
10377           2
10268           2
...
```

Meaning the first time two employees share the same record count is for record count **12252**, where it's shared by **2** employees. Those values are stored and we continue.

To perform the first pass on the first bucket, this is the code. This is where the while loop will start.

We find the lowest id and corresponding record count that isn't assigned to a bucket yet, whose record count is lower than the number of records still left to be filled for the current bucket.

```
SELECT TOP 1
       @currentID = id
     , @numberOfRecords = records_for_emp
FROM #bucket_mapping
WHERE bucket_id = 0
      AND id > @currentID
      AND records_for_emp <= (@maxBucketSize - @currentBucketSize)
ORDER BY id;
```

In my dataset, the first 3 records were these -

```
id          records_for_emp
----------- ------------
1           39980
2           39872
3           39774
...
```

Meaning the record with the id of 1 and record count of **39980** were stored.

The next bit of code looks to see if this record count is the start of a run of data items or a single data item. Since we know the first run of data items in my example dataset has a record count of **12252**, this is a single data item.

We check to see if the current bucket can hold the record count stored for the current id. In my example dataset, I have **214,214,960 records** and I want to split them across **50** buckets, so with a maximum size of **4,284,299** records per bucket, **39980** can absolutely fit. We update the mapping table and set the currently unassigned bucket_id of 0 to the bucket_id of the current bucket, **1**, and update the current_bucket_size to reflect the newly added data item, **39980**.

```
IF @numberOfRecords = @batchThreshold
BEGIN
-- code processing runs of data items
END;
ELSE IF @currentBucketSize + @records_for_emp <= @maxBucketSize
BEGIN
    UPDATE #bucket_mapping
    SET bucket_id = @currentBucket
    WHERE id = @currentID;

    SELECT @currentBucketSize += @records_for_emp
END;
```

This code will continue to loop, finding the next data item not assigned to a bucket that can fit into the space remaining in my current bucket, and add them one after the next until the bucket is full. When that occurs or when we've finished processing everything there is to process, the code below will run, advancing the @currentBucket variable by 1 and resetting the @currentID and @currentBucketSize variables back to 0. This is placed just below the code above in the while loop.

```
IF @currentBucketSize >= @maxBucketSize
   OR @currentID >= @totalRecords
   OR @lastID = @currentID
BEGIN
    SELECT @currentID = 0
         , @currentBucket += 1
         , @currentBucketSize = 0;
END;

SET @lastID = @currentID;
```

In the event that the current bucket is under the @maxBucketSize by a given number, *n*, and there are no single data items with a record count of n or runs of data that add up to n, this will spin into an infinite loop. To prevent this, after each loop we set a placeholder variable, @lastID, to hold the current id that was just processed. At the end of the next loop, we evaluate the id we just processed, and if it is the same value as the last id we processed, we advance to the next bucket and reset the values as if the bucket were full.

My first bucket looks like this -

```
id          emp_id      records_for_emp bucket_id   current_bucket_size
----------- ----------- --------------- ----------- -------------------
1           2241032     39980           1           39980
2           2464976     39872           1           79852
3           2377353     39774           1           119626
...
131         2191316     22912           1           4254752
132         2675322     22817           1           4277569
15114       1973944     6729            1           4284298
225224      2719573     1               1           4284299

(134 rows affected)
```

In this first bucket, it just happens to be that all the data items were single data items, making this first bucket contain **134 employees** and all of their records over **134 loops**.

**Let's take a second to talk about efficiency and performance**

That comes out to **1 row processed per 1 loop**, which is *really bad* for performance on large datasets. My dataset in particular contains **284378 employees**, and I'm not about to run that many loops to sort this data. Even looking at the last id inserted in my bucket above, **225224**, my total number of employees, **284378**, and my largest record count for data items in a run, **12252** - it's completely obvious that this dataset contains a lot of data items belonging to several runs. So what happens when those record counts are next on our list to be processed? When we continue into the next bucket we will see.

As this loop starts and iterates through the single data items, it treks along until it reaches the first data item of the first run of data.

```
id          emp_id      records_for_emp bucket_id   current_bucket_size
----------- ----------- --------------- ----------- -------------------
133         2224239     22422           2           22422
134         2030382     22408           2           44830
135         2822187     22071           2           66901
...
292         2684064     12371           2           2719655
293         2771062     12365           2           2732020
294         325574      12252           ???         ???
```

If you'll recall, we initialized the @batchThreshold and @lengthOfRun variables with the record count of the run, **12252**, and the number of data items in the run, **2**. Instead of looping through both of these 1 by 1, we can handle them as an entire run of data in one loop. To achieve that, we add this code before the code that handles the single data items in this way -

```
IF @numberOfRecords = @batchThreshold
BEGIN
    IF (@maxBucketSize - @currentBucketSize) < (@batchThreshold * @lengthOfRun)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @lengthOfRun = (@maxBucketSize - @currentBucketSize) / @batchThreshold;
    END;

    SELECT @batchEndID = @currentID + (@lengthOfRun - 1);

    UPDATE #bucket_mapping
    SET bucket_id = @currentBucket
    WHERE id
    BETWEEN @currentID AND @batchEndID;

    SELECT @currentBucketSize += (@batchThreshold * @lengthOfRun)

    SELECT TOP 1
           @batchThreshold = records_for_emp
         , @lengthOfRun = COUNT(1)
    FROM #bucket_mapping
    WHERE bucket_id = 0
          AND records_for_emp <= (@maxBucketSize - @currentBucketSize)
    GROUP BY records_for_emp
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
    ORDER BY records_for_emp DESC;
END;
ELSE IF @currentBucketSize + @records_for_emp <= @maxBucketSize
BEGIN
    UPDATE #bucket_mapping
    SET bucket_id = @currentBucket
    WHERE id = @currentID;

    SELECT @currentBucketSize += @records_for_emp
END;
```

Since the condition to execute the code that processes runs of data items is satisfied, we look to see if the entire size of the run is larger than what can fit into the remaining size of the current bucket. Since our current bucket size is **2,732,020** and our max bucket size is **4,284,299**, we have plenty of room to fit the entire run of **2** data items, each having a record count of **12252**.

If that were not the case, we would evaluate exactly how many data items in the run *can* fit into the remaining size of the current bucket and set the @lengthOfRun variable to that value.

Since the first data item in this run being processed is the current id, we simply add the **length of the run - 1** to the current id to get the id of the record ending the run, since the BETWEEN operator is inclusive of the first and last parameters.

We update our run of data items to the current bucket id and add the total number of records across the run to the current bucket size. Finally, we find and store the next largest record count and run length of data items in a run where at least 1 of those data items can fit into the remaining size of the current bucket.

With the code that handles runs of data items in effect, this is my second bucket -

```
id          emp_id      records_for_emp bucket_id   current_bucket_size
----------- ----------- --------------- ----------- -------------------
133         2224239     22422           2           22422
134         2030382     22408           2           44830
135         2822187     22071           2           66901
...
434         2731969     10230           2           4267126
435         2620227     10229           2           4277355
14875       1940363     6944            2           4284299

(304 rows affected)
```

For this bucket, **6 runs** of **2 data items** were processed, eliminating **6 loops** for this bucket. We can count the number of loops with a variable and subtract the number of data items processed to find the number of loops saved, or we can use this formula -

*sum(number_of_runs * run_length) - sum(number_of_runs) = loops eliminated*

With that, we can see we executed **298 loops** for this bucket - a compression ratio of **304:298** or **1.02 rows per loop**. That's still pretty bad, but my third bucket is where the runs really ramp up.

My third bucket looks like this -

```
id          emp_id      records_for_emp bucket_id   current_bucket_size
----------- ----------- --------------- ----------- -------------------
436         2654078     10228           3           10228
437         2724211     10226           3           20454
438         2637132     10225           3           30679
...
858         2642083     10039           3           4269902
859         423751      10039           3           4279941
18409       1816222     4358            3           4284299

(425 rows affected)
```

For the third bucket, there were **92 runs** of data items -

```
runs        run_length
----------- -----------
37          2
11          3
10          4
13          5
6           6
7           7
3           8
2           9
1           10
2           11
```

Altogether, those **92 runs** accounted for **371 rows**, meaning that **146 loops** produced **425 total rows**. This time the compression ratio is **425:146** or **2.91 rows per loop**

This algorithm does best when the inherent properties of the dataset are such that it contains lots of runs. In my datasets, there are lots of runs of smaller values, meaning that the RLE logic works better the higher the current bucket id for smaller total bucket values, but performance scales exponentially until there are no runs, at which point performance will be linear at best and logarithmic at worst, depending on your cpu.

**So now let's talk about the final bucket**

When we begin filling the final bucket, we *could* loop through the remaining employees, adding them one at a time or calculating run length, but why? After this bucket there are no more buckets to put employees in. We can just eliminate any unnecessary loops by just dumping all remaining records into the final bucket instead by running this code before anything else in the while loop.

```
IF (@currentBucket = @totalBucketCount)
BEGIN
    UPDATE #bucket_mapping
    SET bucket_id = @currentBucket
    WHERE bucket_id = 0;
    
    BREAK;
END
```

The problem that comes with this though, is that the final bucket contains some overflow records, and now looks like this -

```
bucket_id   emp_count     total_records
----------- ------------ -------------
1           134          4284299
2           304          4284299
3           425          4284299
...
48          2146         4284299
49          2986         4284299
50          248714       4284309
```

This doesn't look too bad, but it can diverge more when the employees with the fewest records have record counts > 1, such as in this other dataset I have -

```
bucket_id   emp_count    total_records
----------- ------------ -------------
1           5            29076
2           5            29075
3           5            29072
...
198         16           28994
199         19           28892
200         49           52558
```

To solve this and better smooth out our buckets, we introduce passes 2 and 3.

The second pass loops through any data items left over with record counts > 1 and distributes them one at a time to the bucket with the fewest total records at the beginning of the loop. The code for that goes in the section after we dump all the remaining records into the final bucket.

```
DECLARE @spillover TABLE
(
    id INT
  , records_for_emp INT
);

SELECT @currentBucketSize = SUM(records_for_emp)
FROM #bucket_mapping
WHERE bucket_id = @currentBucket;

INSERT INTO @spillover
SELECT TOP (@currentBucketSize - @maxBucketSize)
       id
     , records_for_emp
FROM #bucket_mapping
WHERE bucket_id = @currentBucket
ORDER BY records_for_emp;
```

First we create a table variable to hold the overflow data items. Since the number of overflow data items won't necessarily match the number of overflow records, We have to assume that this will need to work for whatever the @totalBucketCount is, or smaller. We can use the total record difference in determining how many data items to insert into the spillover table. This not only covers when the algorithm is working correctly, but essentially covers any edge cases in which the first pass would not work correctly.

```
WHILE (@currentBucketSize - @maxBucketSize) > 0
      AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @spillover
        WHERE records_for_emp > 1
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT @bucketID = sGrp.bucket_id
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
               bucket_id
             , SUM(records_for_emp) AS total_records
        FROM #bucket_mapping
        GROUP BY bucket_id
        ORDER BY total_records
    ) AS sGrp;

    SELECT TOP 1
           @recordCount = records_for_emp
         , @currentID = id
    FROM @spillover
    WHERE records_for_emp > 1
    ORDER BY records_for_emp;

    UPDATE #bucket_mapping
    SET bucket_id = @bucketID
    WHERE id = @currentID;

    SELECT @currentBucketSize -= @recordCount;

    DELETE FROM @spillover
    WHERE id = @currentID;
END;
```

My first data set had no data items with a record count > 1, so we'll use my second dataset. Grabbing the difference, (top 24000ish records) just grabbed all 49 data items in the bucket. We wont use them all, just enough for the final bucket to be within appropriate size.

Below are the results **after** each iteration of the second pass of the dataset with 24000ish records in difference.

```
target_bucket records_for_emp target_bucket_total current_bucket_total
------------- --------------- ------------------- --------------------
169           825             29182               51733
62            838             29220               50895
61            840             29232               50055
...
40            1079            29675               31185
192           1083            29679               30102
38            1088            29709               29014
```

The third and final pass operates on data items with a row count of only 1, distributing them all to the buckets with the fewest total records in one execution.

```
IF (@currentBucketSize - @maxBucketSize) > 0
    AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM @spillover
    WHERE records_for_emp = 1
)
BEGIN;
    WITH rList
    AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.records_for_emp) AS id
                , g.bucket_id
        FROM #bucket_mapping AS g WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN @spillover AS s
                ON s.id = g.id
    )
        , nRecord_count
    AS
    (
        SELECT TOP (@currentBucketSize - @maxBucketSize)
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY grid.TotalItems) AS id
                , grid.bucket_id
        FROM
        (
            SELECT bucket_id
                    , SUM(records_for_emp) AS TotalItems
            FROM #bucket_mapping WITH (NOLOCK)
            GROUP BY bucket_id
        ) AS grid
    )
    UPDATE r
    SET r.bucket_id = nr.bucket_id
    FROM rList AS r
        INNER JOIN nRecord_count AS nr
            ON nr.id = r.id;
END;
```

Looking back at my first dataset if you recall, I had 10 data items with a record count of 1 left over in the final bucket. Grabbing the difference, TOP 10, grabs those leftover data items and assigns them to the TOP 10 smallest buckets.

Below are the source and destination buckets for the overflow data items.

```
source_bucket_id target_bucket_id
---------------- ----------------
50               49
50               48
50               47
50               46
50               45
50               44
50               43
50               42
50               41
50               40
```

When everything is all said and done, I had **284378** total employees to sort, and after all three passes I've only executed **8356** loops, bringing my full operation to a compression ratio of **284738/8356**, or **34.08 rows per loop**.

Those are the statistics for my given dataset, and my given desired bucket parameter. I'm sure there are better general optimizations, but to load and aggregate the 200+ million rows of data took longer for me than all 3 passes of this sorting algorithm, 4 seconds to load and aggregate, 3 to sort.

**CODE**

```
CREATE TABLE #bucket_mapping
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , emp_id INT NOT NULL
  , records_for_emp INT NOT NULL
  , bucket_id INT NOT NULL
        DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON #bucket_mapping (bucket_id, records_for_emp);

INSERT INTO #bucket_mapping
(
    emp_id
  , records_for_emp
)
SELECT employee_id
     , COUNT(1) as records_for_emp
FROM sourcetable
GROUP BY employee_id
ORDER BY records_for_emp DESC;

DECLARE @currentBucket INT = 1
      , @totalBucketCount INT = 50
      , @currentID INT = 0
      , @lastID INT
      , @recordCount INT
      , @bucketID INT
      , @currentBucketSize INT = 0
      , @maxBucketSize INT
      , @batchThreshold INT
      , @batchRange INT
      , @batchEndID INT
      , @totalRecordCount INT;

SELECT TOP 1
       @batchThreshold = records_for_emp
     , @batchRange = COUNT(1)
FROM #bucket_mapping WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE bucket_id = 0
GROUP BY records_for_emp
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY records_for_emp DESC;

SELECT @totalRecordCount = SUM(records_for_emp)
     , @maxBucketSize = SUM(records_for_emp) / @totalBucketCount
FROM #bucket_mapping WITH (NOLOCK);

SELECT @maxBucketSize;

WHILE (@currentBucket <= @totalBucketCount)
BEGIN
    IF (@currentBucket = @totalBucketCount)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #bucket_mapping
        SET bucket_id = @currentBucket
        WHERE bucket_id = 0;

        DECLARE @spillover TABLE
        (
            id INT
          , records_for_emp INT
        );

        SELECT @currentBucketSize = SUM(records_for_emp)
        FROM #bucket_mapping WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE bucket_id = @currentBucket;

        INSERT INTO @spillover
        SELECT TOP (@currentBucketSize - @maxBucketSize)
               id
             , records_for_emp
        FROM #bucket_mapping WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE bucket_id = @currentBucket
        ORDER BY records_for_emp;

        WHILE (@currentBucketSize - @maxBucketSize) > 0
              AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM @spillover WHERE records_for_emp > 1
    )
        BEGIN
            SELECT @bucketID = sGrp.bucket_id
            FROM
            (
                SELECT TOP 1
                       bucket_id
                     , SUM(records_for_emp) AS total_records
                FROM #bucket_mapping
                GROUP BY bucket_id
                ORDER BY total_records
            ) AS sGrp;

            SELECT TOP 1
                   @recordCount = records_for_emp
                 , @currentID = id
            FROM @spillover
            WHERE records_for_emp > 1
            ORDER BY records_for_emp;

            UPDATE #bucket_mapping
            SET bucket_id = @bucketID
            WHERE id = @currentID;

            SELECT @currentBucketSize -= @recordCount;

            DELETE FROM @spillover
            WHERE id = @currentID;
        END;

        IF (@currentBucketSize - @maxBucketSize) > 0
            AND EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM @spillover
            WHERE records_for_emp = 1
        )
        BEGIN;
            WITH rList
            AS
            (
                SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.records_for_emp) AS id
                        , g.bucket_id
                FROM #bucket_mapping AS g WITH (NOLOCK)
                    INNER JOIN @spillover AS s
                        ON s.id = g.id
            )
                , nrecords_for_emp
            AS
            (
                SELECT TOP (@currentBucketSize - @maxBucketSize)
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY grid.TotalItems) AS id
                        , grid.bucket_id
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT bucket_id
                            , SUM(records_for_emp) AS TotalItems
                    FROM #bucket_mapping WITH (NOLOCK)
                    GROUP BY bucket_id
                ) AS grid
            )
            UPDATE r
            SET r.bucket_id = nr.bucket_id
            FROM rList AS r
                INNER JOIN nrecords_for_emp AS nr
                    ON nr.id = r.id;
        END;
        BREAK;
    END;

    SELECT TOP 1
           @currentID = id
         , @recordCount = records_for_emp
    FROM #bucket_mapping WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE bucket_id = 0
          AND id > @currentID
          AND records_for_emp <= (@maxBucketSize - @currentBucketSize)
    ORDER BY id;

    IF @recordCount = @batchThreshold
    BEGIN
        IF (@maxBucketSize - @currentBucketSize) < (@batchThreshold * @batchRange)
        BEGIN
            SELECT @batchRange = (@maxBucketSize - @currentBucketSize) / @batchThreshold;
        END;

        SELECT @batchEndID = @currentID + (@batchRange - 1);

        UPDATE #bucket_mapping
        SET bucket_id = @currentBucket
        WHERE id
        BETWEEN @currentID AND @batchEndID;

        SELECT @currentBucketSize += (@batchRange * @batchThreshold);

        SELECT TOP 1
               @batchThreshold = records_for_emp
             , @batchRange = COUNT(1)
        FROM #bucket_mapping WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE bucket_id = 0
              AND records_for_emp <= (@maxBucketSize - @currentBucketSize)
        GROUP BY records_for_emp
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
        ORDER BY records_for_emp DESC;
    END;
    ELSE IF @currentBucketSize + @recordCount <= @maxBucketSize
    BEGIN
        UPDATE #bucket_mapping
        SET bucket_id = @currentBucket
        WHERE id = @currentID;

        SELECT @currentBucketSize += @recordCount;
    END;

    IF @currentBucketSize >= @maxBucketSize
       OR @currentID >= @totalRecordCount
       OR @lastID = @currentID
    BEGIN
        SELECT @currentID = 0
             , @currentBucket += 1
             , @currentBucketSize = 0;

        SELECT TOP 1
               @batchThreshold = records_for_emp
             , @batchRange = COUNT(1)
        FROM #bucket_mapping WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE bucket_id = 0
        GROUP BY records_for_emp
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
        ORDER BY records_for_emp DESC;
    END;

    SET @lastID = @currentID;
END;

SELECT bucket_id
     , COUNT(1) AS records_for_emp
     , SUM(records_for_emp) AS total_records
FROM #bucket_mapping
GROUP BY bucket_id
ORDER BY bucket_id;
```

**REGARDING THE DATASET OF THE ORIGINAL ASKER**

In your example, the size of your final bucket was under the other 3. In this solution, not only is the final bucket intended to be larger than the rest due to overflow data items, but passes 2 and 3 are designed for error handling and redistribution of those overflow data items.

To make this solution work for your specific example, you would only need to make a few changes. The first would be to comment out passes 2 and 3, and the second would only need to be to adjust the *@maxBucketSize* variable to be calculated as -

**@maxBucketSize = (@totalRecords / @totalBucketCount) + 1**.

That actually yields a different combination of values, but equates to the same answer you are looking for, I believe.

```
  1    2    3    4
---  ---  ---  ---
 10    9    8    7
  4    5    6    3
                 2
                 1
---  ---  ---  ---
 14   14   14   13
```