# ADF patterns to minimise batch run elapsed time

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory

We use Azure Data Factory (ADF) to pull a number of source tables from an on-prem SQL Server DB into Azure Data Lake (DL). We've made this data-driven using the Lookup-ForEach pattern.

There is one big table, a couple of large-ish ones and several small ones. They range from 400GB to 1MB.

[image: Size in GB for source tables]
*fig 1: Tables' sizes. The distribution is very skewed.*

The degree of run-time parallelism is controlled by the ADF ForEach activity's Batch Count parameter. I think of this as the number of work queues, or "workers" available.

The standard implementation distributes items over workers in a [round-robin fashion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/292715/how-are-tasks-assigned-to-foreach-iterations) in advance of execution. This means there will always be tasks queued behind the largest table. This needlessly increases the overall elapsed time. Manual investigation suggests if the largest table is given its own worker all the other tables can fit into three other workers and the elapsed times come out somewhat uniform.

[image]
*fig 2: Arranging observed elapsed times so the largest table (dark blue) has its own worker yields fairly even end times.*

What techniques or patterns to allocate work to workers can I implement so that the overall elapsed time is minimized?

We can vary ADF and the DL as we like. The corresponding Integration Runtime (IR) is finite, however. We cannot just scale out to resolve the situation.

The source system is third-party. Small modifications can be accommodated but major source table refactoring would not be possible.

We will be adding further source tables. A solution which requires minimal re-coding as sources are added would be preferable. The system is under active maintenance so necessary changes will be implemented.

Each source table's size will vary from day-to-day but not hugely. If the table holds 20GB today it may be 19GB or 21GB tomorrow, but it will not be terabytes.

So yes, this is a scheduling problem with the number of items, their relative sizes and the number of queues fairly stable.

#### Related

[Select data divided in groups evenly distributed by value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127920/select-data-divided-in-groups-evenly-distributed-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

[Select data divided in groups evenly distributed by value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127920/select-data-divided-in-groups-evenly-distributed-by-value) This answer will help to distribute the weight into 4 workers.
However, Each worker still has equal amount of jobs to execute.

Modify it a bit:

```
 UPDATE w
    SET w.grp=(CASE w._row
               WHEN x._pos_row THEN x._neg_grp
               ELSE w.grp END), 
        w.moved=(CASE w._row
               WHEN x._pos_row THEN w.moved+1
               ELSE w.moved END) -- only change group for possitive one
    FROM @work AS w
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TOP 1 pos._row AS _pos_row, pos.grp AS _pos_grp,
                     neg._row AS _neg_row, neg.grp AS _neg_grp
        FROM cte AS pos
        INNER JOIN cte AS neg ON
            pos._grpoffset>0 AND
            neg._grpoffset<0 AND
            --- To prevent infinite recursion:
            pos.moved<4 AND
            neg.moved<4
        WHERE  --- trade off between move data from positive to negative side
            ABS(neg.[time]+pos.[time])<=ABS(pos.[time])
        --- Largest changes first:
        ORDER BY ABS(pos.[time]+neg.[time]) DESC
        ) AS x ON w._row IN (x._pos_row, x._neg_row);
```

Now, workers does not have the equal amount of job. However, the weights are actually distributed as your Optimal Packing figure.

Later than, we can use a forEach to call a executed pipeline 4 time (in parallel, using the group as parameter). For each group, you can execute your pipeline in sequential.
[image]

[image]

Finally, 4 parallel pipeline will run in the optimal time.

Answer (score 0):

If we understand the problem to be the ForEach pushing additional tasks onto the queue behind the very large task, this can be addressed by implementing a pull mechanism instead.

We can achieve this by side-stepping the queuing built into the Lookup-ForEach pattern. Rather, we initiate only enough workers to provide the degree of parallelism we desire, and have these pull tasks.

The parallelism of a ForEach is controlled by its Batch Count. At the time of writing this has a maximum value of 50 and cannot be set dynamically at run-time. We will set this value to its maximum (50) and control effective run-time parallelism through application code. Let's call our application value AppBatchCount. The desired run-time value can be held in a global parameter, pipeline parameter, DBMS config table or whatever mechanism is convenient (activity "A" in the diagram below). If we want four parallel workers in the ForEach AppBatchCount will have the value 4.

Populate an array variable using the expression `@range(1, AppBatchCount)` (activity "B" below). It is this array variable which is mapped to the Items of the ForEach (activity "C" below). In this way the value of AppBatchCount directly affects the number of parallel workers given activities to run.

Inside the ForEach are activities to perform the work required to fulfil a task. It is often convenient to package these in a separate pipeline. This pipline will have an Until activity controlled by variable. Let's call that variable "LoopAgain". Inside the Until a task is dequeued. If a task is obtained, LoopAgain is set "true" and the task is performed. If no task is dequeued LoopAgain is set "false" and the Until exits, terminating this worker.

How a task is dequeued will depend on the technology used to hold it. For SQL Server this is a [well-known](https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) task. Other technologies will have their own techniques. Tasks will be dequeued in size order, largest (i.e. longest running) first.

Taking the distribution from figure 2 in the question as an example, and using 4 workers, the four biggest tasks will be started first, one on each worker. The 4th largest task will finish first (by definition) and start work on the fifth largest task. This will continue until workers 2-4 have exhausted the queue and terminated. Eventually worker 1 will finish the largest task, look for more work, find there is none left to do and terminate too. So no work is queued behind the largest task and elapsed time is minimised.

New source tables can be added by inserting them to the queue with an appropriate estimation of their size. Indeed, actual processing time can be logged and processing sequences adjusted automatically as sources change over time.

[image]

ADF Pipeline definition

```
{
    "name": "ForEach pull",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "BatchCountArray",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get AppBatchCount",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "BatchCountArray",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@range(1, int(activity('Get AppBatchCount').output.firstRow.AppBatchCount))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Pull tasks",
                "description": "Set Batch Count to the maximum permitted. The actual number will be controlled by the size of BatchCountArray.",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "BatchCountArray",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@variables('BatchCountArray')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": false,
                    "batchCount": 50,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "ForEach pull worker",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "ForEach pull worker",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                "parameters": {
                                    "WorkerNumber": {
                                        "value": "1",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Get AppBatchCount",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": []
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "Worker": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "4"
            },
            "BatchCountArray": {
                "type": "Array"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be understood to be due to the units of work being of different sizes. One way to tackle that would be to break up each large table into several smaller parts.  These parts I will call "shards".

In the worst case a single worker will be processing the last shard after all other workers have finished their alloted tasks. We can decide the duration of this imbalance we are willing to tolerate and calculate the number of shards accordingly. Say the system is able to process the 400GB source in 1h40m (100 minutes). That's 4GB per minute. If we're willing to have a lonely worker for 10 minutes each shard will be 40GB and there will be 10 shards for the biggest table. Smaller tables can be left as a single shard.

Likely there will be some overhead for a worker starting and completing a task. If we produce a great many tiny shards this cumulative overhead may actually increase the overall elapsed time.

In reality workers do not start and complete tasks in perfect synchrony even if the tasks are of equal size. This drift could go either way - causing the difference in elapsed time for the last-finishing and second-last finishing to be either more or less than our chosen tolerance. Small tables are in workers' queues, too, increasing variablility. Moreover, if a worker stalls for whatever reason it will finish much later than predicted. Consequently it would be beneficial to combine this "sharding" approach with the "pull" approach in another answer.

Sharding would not be efficient if each worker had to scan the entire input table to find its rows. This could occur if a worker implemented a modulo-based read. Rather we would prefer a worker scaned a contiguous range of the source table. This implies there is an index on some highly selective column(s), ideally a serial/ identity with unique values.

How do we find the upper and lower key boundries for each shard? A scan of the source table would be accurate but slow. Reading the minimum and maximum, subtracting, and dividing by the number of shards will be fast. This may produce unbalanced shards if there are gaps in the key range, perhaps because of archiving. After a run has completed the actual number of rows per key range is known and the ranges can be adjusted accordingly for the following run, allowing for expected growth in the source table. The lower bound of the first shard and the upper bound of the last should be minus/plus infinity respectively to catch all rows in the table.